# Generate positive correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

How can I generate a positive correlation matrix in R, where the correlation coefficients are uniformly distributed?

My approach to date has resulted in values which are not uniformly distributed, or include negative values.
e.g.

1) `rcorrmatrix(k, alphad = 1)` from the `clusterGeneration` package results in uniform distribution (-1,1).

2) creating a uniform random (0,1) matrix and then applying the `nearPD` function (from `Matrix` package) to ensure the matrix is positive definite, results in a distribution around 0.5, with variance ~ 0.1, so there are few/no values >0.8

any thoughts?

Comment: Just an idea, not sure: `abs(rcorrmatrix(k, alphad = 1))`.

Comment: yeah - but the result, irritatingly, is not positive definite for large values. And applying the nearPD function gives a very 0-skewed distribution.

Comment: Correlation matrix is property of the data. Are you generating correlation matrix, or, the related data?

Comment: @Heikki I want to use the correlation matrix to generate a set of multivariate random normal variables